# Discord invite url launch issue with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, discord

We have an app that opens the discord channel invite link by url_launcher.
Starting from the new version of the discord app, out the flutter app, open discord invite into flutter sandbox(?) or in-app webview (?), but not in discord app.
Actually, after append invite, it opens the discord app, but in our app, we stuck on the discord screen too.

Tried to downgrade flutter version and url_launcher version, but nothing helps. Only downgrade discord apk version helps.
Any view on how to solve this problem?

```
flutter version 1.22.6

url_lauhcner version 5.7.10
```

discord apk version `53.8` and `60.3`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Discord url test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Discord url test'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Press button to open discord invite'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          await launch('https://discord.gg/QkkDwuC86w');
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

how it should work (discord apk version 53.8)

[image]

how it works now (discord apk version 60.3)

[image]

[good case video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MeOwtxkwzvxZ6oqYCcSxaG8DnlpGtGz7/view?usp=sharing)

[bad case video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hoUSW1LGx-bv9lhXC0sov0mV7Sqz_dyb/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foun solution here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75584

you can fix that behavior by changing the default Activity's Launch Mode to singleInstance.

In android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml :

```
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```